# Finding the limit of perimeters of polygons

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Prove that a sequence of lengths of perimeters of regular $2^n$-gons inscribed in a circle tends to a limit (called the length of circumference).

How do I get $\pi$ while calculating the limit

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the length of one side of the regular polygon, then $x^2 = r^2 + r^2 - 2r^2\cos \theta = 4r^2\sin^2 \left(\theta/2\right) \Rightarrow x = 2r\sin \left(\theta/2\right) = 2r\sin \left(\dfrac{\dfrac{2\pi}{2^n}}{2}\right) = 2r\sin \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right) \Rightarrow C_n = 2^nx = 2^{n+1}r\sin \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right) = 2\pi r\cdot \dfrac{\sin \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}{\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}} \rightarrow 2\pi r = 2\pi$ if $r = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the perimeter of a regular m-gon inscribed in a circle of radius $r$ is given by $$p=2 m r \sin\big(\frac{\pi}{m}\big)$$ rewrite the formula as $$p=2 \pi r\frac{m}{\pi}\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{m}\big)=2 \pi r\frac{\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{m}\big)}{\frac{\pi}{m}}$$ Now, consider that $m$ becomes larger and larger and remember the limit of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ when $x$ tends to $0$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the circumference of the regular $2^n$-gon $P_n$ by $U_n$ $(n\geq2)$. From the construction it is obvious that the $U_n$ form an increasing sequence. In order to prove that the $\lim_{n\to\infty} U_n$ exists it therefore suffices to prove that the $U_n$ are bounded above. I claim that

$$ U_n\leq8\qquad\forall n\geq2\ .$$
*Proof.* Denote the  vertices of $P_n$ by $${\bf z}_k=(x_k,y_k)\qquad (1\leq k\leq N:=2^n)$$ in cyclic order. Since $$|{\bf z}_k-{\bf z}_{k-1}|\leq|x_k-x_{k-1}|+|y_k-y_{k-1}|$$ we obtain
$$U_n=\sum_{k=1}^N |{\bf z}_k-{\bf z}_{k-1}|\leq \sum_{k=1}^N |x_k-x_{k-1}|+\sum_{k=1}^N |y_k-y_{k-1}|=4+4=8\ .\qquad\square$$
It is customary to denote the $\lim_{n\to\infty} U_n$ by $2\pi$.